# dbGetQuery continuously running against Sybase DB - no results returned

Tags: sql, r, odbc, sap-iq

I have a table in a Sybase DB with ~20M rows across 45 columns. I need to pull the entire contents into a dataframe in R.

I am using the odbc package in R to send my query to the Sybase DB but the query never completes, that is I have left it running overnight and it is still not completed the next morning.

I have used the same package to pull the first 1M rows and this works fine and takes ~10mins.

My DB version is

```
SAP IQ/16.0.110.2805/11355/P/sp11.20/RS6000MP/AIX 6.1.0/64bit/2018-06-15 10:01:05
```

My query looks as follows:

```
data <- dbGetQuery(db_conn,"SELECT *
                   FROM mytable.claims")
```

Here is some info about the connection I am using:

```
> dbGetInfo(db_conn)
$dbname
[1] "THEDATABASE"

$dbms.name
[1] "Sybase IQ"

$db.version
[1] "16.10.0010"

$username
[1] "myname"

$host
[1] ""

$port
[1] ""

$sourcename
[1] "SomethingHere"

$servername
[1] "SomethingHere"

$drivername
[1] "dbodbc16.dll"

$odbc.version
[1] "03.80.0000"

$driver.version
[1] "16.00.1215"

$odbcdriver.version
[1] "03.52"

$supports.transactions
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "Sybase IQ"   "driver_info" "list"
```

I would be keen to hear from anyone that has experienced similar issues with this database and package

Comment: What about your client platform?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I am using RStudio 64bit to send the SQL query to my database using the odbc package